# Is Aviation's number of answers correct?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, statistics, beta-sites

After noticing our [Q:A ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation) hasn't moved off 1.9 for about a week, I just calculated the ratio, based on [1,333](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1333) posts; [377](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqr1z.png) of which are questions:

```
(1333 - 377) / 377 = 2.54
```

But that means that there should be 956 answers, whereas the site home shows 716 answers.

Have we really had 240 answers deleted; or are our stats being calculated incorrectly?

Comment: Where did you get 1333 from?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Look at the URL the number 1,333 is linked to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the stats from the [main page of Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com):

[image: Site Stats]

So, you get:

```
716 / 377 = 1.899 (close enough to 1.9 for me)
```

As @Qantas94Heavy pointed out, 1,333 also includes tag wiki's/excerpts so you can't use the number from the URL as a "counter" to see how many posts there are.

Comment: Exactly. So where are the missing posts? Our post count is up to 1,333. I've flagged to migrate this to MSO (I guess the migrate option is hidden from the close menu in beta).

Comment: @DannyBeckett: post count is also incremented for tag wikis/excerpts.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It seems odd that tags would be assigned a post ID. To check this though, taking the *air-traffic-control* tag as an example; it has ID 28, but `http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/28` links to a question, not the tag. So that theory appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: it's mainly for revisions -- see http://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/460/revisions (a tag wiki excerpt) as an example.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: don't know where you're getting 28 from, the excerpt's here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/369/revisions. Typing in http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/369 just links back to the tag page.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy The 28 is from http://aviation.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/28 but you're right, I'm seeing the ID 369 now. Can you make all this into an answer?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: ah, I see. Tags probably have both their own count _and_ the post counts for their wikis.